# NGINX | Отдать содержимое другого файла

Tags: nginx

```
location ~* ^/test.txt/*$
{
  default_type text/plain;
  alias /home/123.txt;
}
```

Необходимо при подключении к `example.com/test.txt` отдавать содержимое файла `/home/123.txt`.

При  переходе на `example.com/test.txt` все ОК, при переходе на `example.com/test.txt/` 500 ошибка:

> "/home/123.txtindex.html" is not a directory, client: ***, server: ***, request: "GET /test.txt/ HTTP/1.1", host: "***"

Как решить? Спасибо.

Comment: А что должно быть при обращении к example.com/test.txt/ ?

Comment: @bukkojot `location ~* ^/test.txt/*$` должен обрабатывать запросы и без слеша и со слешем на конце. Значит, при подключении к `example.com/test.txt/` должен отдаваться файл `/home/123.txt` как и указано в location, но происходит ошибка, nginx думает, что `/home/123.txt` это директория и ищет в ней файл `index.html`.

Answer (score 2):

```
server {
    # ...
    rewrite ^(/download/.*)/media/(\w+)\.?.*$ $1/mp3/$2.mp3 last;
    rewrite ^(/download/.*)/audio/(\w+)\.?.*$ $1/mp3/$2.ra  last;
    return  403;
    # ...
}
```

[Официальная документация](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/)

Answer (score 0):

Для таких целей надо использовать rewrite.

```
location /test.txt {
    rewrite ^/.* http://example.com/home/123.txt permanent;
}

location /test.txt/ {
    rewrite ^/.* http://example.com/home/123.txt permanent;
}
```

Comment: `/home/123.txt` в вопросе это абсолютный путь, а не URI

Comment: @AlexeyTen ну и напишите более лучший ответ вместо того, чтобы минусовать. Первый location просто скопирован с реального сервера,и он работает. Адрес example.com/test.txt перенаправляется на http://example.com/home/123.txt. И что не соответствует вопросу? Второй location написан по аналогии.

Comment: Минус === ответ не является полезным. Ничего личного.

Comment: Я предпочитаю писать ответы после того, как автор ответит на уточняющие вопросы.

Answer (score 0):

Исправим регулярку и ее режим работы, добавим переопределение запроса и удалим алиасы, которые тут не нужны, получим:

```
location ~ ^/test.txt.* {
  rewrite .* /etc/passwd break;
  root /;
}
```

Comment: Судя по ответам регулярка должна быть такой `^/test\.txt/?$`

Comment: Если матчить только /test.txt и /test.txt/ - да, моя поматчит любое начинающееся на /test.txt, включая /test1txt

Comment: Я на 146% уверен, что автор не хотел test1txt